# how would i set the value for this variable?

Tags: c#

I have been given this interface to start with. There are a number of functions I must implement.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public interface IInfoCard
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Category { get; }
    string GetDataAsString();
    void DisplayData(Panel displayPanel);
    void CloseDisplay();
    bool EditData();
}
```

How would I implement the following function into the interface.

```
class Class2 : IInfoCard
    {
     public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The implementation is up to you as how you want it to be.

Comment: Related - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161166/should-i-prefer-properties-with-or-without-private-fields

Answer (score 0):

You should use then `Abstract` classes, not interfaces, then.

```
public abstract class IInfoCard
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Category { get; }
    string GetDataAsString() { return null; }
    void DisplayData(Panel displayPanel) {}
    void CloseDisplay() {}
    bool EditData() { return true;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement a property. You can basically encapsulate a field.
An easy way to do that is using [auto-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option 1:**

Make them Auto properties, in which  case compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field.

```
 public string Name {get;set};
```

**Option 2**

Defining an explicit backing field, a private field.

```
private string name;
 public string Name
 {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Class2 : IInfoCard
    {
     private  string _name;
     public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Auto-Implemented Properties**

```
public class Class2 : IInfoCard
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

[See More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)